# Block facebook from my website

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, redirect, ip

I have a secure link direction service I'm running ([expiringlinks.co](http://expiringlinks.co)). If I change the headers in php to redirect my visitors, then facebook is able to show a preview of the website I'm redirecting to when users send links to one another via facebook. I wish to avoid this. Right now, I'm using an AJAX call to get the URL and javascript to redirect, but it's causing problems for users who don't use javascript.

Here are a number of ways I'd like to block facebook, but I can't seem to get working:

1. I've tried blocking the facebook bot (facebookexternalhit/1.0 and facebookexternalhit/1.1) but it's not working, I don't think they're using them for this functionality.
2. I'm thinking of blocking the facebook IP addresses, but I can't find all of them, and I don't think it'll work unless I get all of them.
3. I've thought of using a CAPTCHA or even a button, but I can't bring myself to do that to my visitors. Not to mention I don't think anyone would use the site.
4. I've searched the facebook docs for meta tags that would "opt-me out", but haven't found one, and doubt that I would trust it if I had.

Any creative ideas or any idea how to implement the ones above? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: How did you learn about `(facebookexternalhit/1.0 and facebookexternalhit/1.1)`? Was it through their docs or have dumped visitor user agents? Personally I'd try setting up a log of all user's user-agents and then creating a link, and getting Facebook to create a preview for this link. If you find one that could be for Facebook, block it, see what happens. Facebook also use several URLs which act as proxies for external content, such as `http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php`

Comment: I read about the bots online, from their docs and other sources. I've been using Piwik for analytics, and can't detect facebook when I share links. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the URLs as proxies.

Comment: They use scripts from domains other than their "facebook.com" domain to load your content. They also cache the content and if the same content is requested again (like the image), Facebook will load their cached version instead of your version. That may also be in play here if you're trying to link to the same URL more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - it works for me ...

```
<?php 
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if (preg_match('/facebookexternalhit/si',$ua)) { 
header('Location: no_fb_page.php'); 
die() ; 
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get the logfile of your Webserver, and search there for unusal useragents. (maybe containing facebook) 
Or, otherwise get the Logs and delete every containing internet explorer/firefox/opera...
Then you should have only bots useragents in the end.
Then you could search for the facebook one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a meta refresh instead of a javascript redirect. They work for all browsers and because the page still returns a 200 response any crawler should stop resolving there.

Comment: I like your approach, but can't help but thinking that if the Facebook  link crawler detects the redirecting HTTP headers, why not also detect META redirects?

Comment: Because HTTP headers are sent as part of the response, which the bot has to understand to function, the meta refresh is client-side and would require the bot to parse the response and identify the refresh. 
Obviously something it could do, but if I was writing a bot to resolve URLs I might tell it to stop resolving once it recieved a 200 response. Worth a go though.

Comment: Now a days, Facebook also getting smart to identify meta refresh tag.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is appropriately set up robots.txt.

http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: ... provided Facebook actually obeys this rules. Is it the case?

Comment: @glglgl, I haven't tried it, but would be seriously shocked if such a major player online didn't follow something as basic as `robots.txt`, if anything for legal reasons related to the indexing and storage of content from other sites.  If you have tried it, and know otherwise, please post.

Comment: I don't know either, but while `robots.txt` is quite basic it is not a standard at all, and I don't think they could be legally blamed for nit using it. And as they don't care about privacy at all, I'm not sure they will do so if they are merely told to by a `robots.txt`. If I am wrong, we have luck...

Comment: They do not consider facebookexternalhit bound by the rules of robots.txt
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716531/facebook-and-crawl-delay-in-robots-txt