# How to identify a Facebook bot?

Tags: facebook, validation, bots

is there a way to reliably identify a facebook bot by IP?

My site is getting hammered by bots claiming to be facebook, but how do I know for sure?
I'm looking for some kind of official procedure to validate a facebook bot similar to what Google recommends for their bots [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=80553).

Can I perhaps parse `OrgName` in `whois` and trust that? Or can that be fake?

Comment: You could check the IP addresses, if they are from the officially published ranges: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859013/whats-the-ip-address-range-of-facebooks-open-graph-crawler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering this for the sake of keyword indexing in the internets.

Indeed, it looks like the best way to identify a Facebook bot (Facebook Scraper) is by matching IP to the range of declared official Facebook IP ranges that can be acquired by running

```
whois -h whois.radb.net '!gAS32934'
```

Comment: Updated query from [Facebook's site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#crawl):
whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route

>>Returns similar info, but with two differences:
1) Includes IPv6 addresses as well.
2) The output format is different. No messy "A1063" and "C" before and after the list. Each address in a separate row, including the type (route or route6)

Comment: whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just check the `user-agent`, such as

```
facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
```

instead of `IP`?

Comment: Because _every_ bot can send whatever it likes for a user agent – and the topic of this question was to discern possible fake bots _pretending_ to be Facebook’s scraper from “the real thing” … and that’s exactly the reason why Facebook provides access to the list of the IPs they’re using …

Comment: `user-agent` can be fake as whatever you want