# Facebook 'Like' button doesn't use ':og' tags

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ember.js

I'm currently developing an Ember.js application, and i have huge troubles with social buttons. I did some research here already, but it was of little help.

My application uses history API, `og:` tags are properly changed on page transition, but Facebook still use initial values from my `index.html` page. Calling `FB.XFBML.parse()` doesn't help either.

Also, FB OpenGraph Debugger displays info from my `index.html` for any page, and as a result, i can't even debug what's wrong with it.

So, have anybody encountered anything like this, and possibly figured out an appropriate workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experiencing is expected behavior. The Facebook **scraper** will examine your URL and extract the `og` tags that are present (if any).

Your application may very well change the content of the page dynamically (as is done with single page applications) but the Facebook **scraper** does not run any of your JavaScript so it just see's the initially loaded `index.html` page.

You could imagine that Facebook is using some sort of `cURL` or `wget` - tools that can not (and should not) parse/execute JavaScript or CSS. The **scraper** doesn't run in a browser - it doesn't necessarily see exactly the same thing a normal user would.

---

In order to be able to provide multiple "like" plugins your application will need to be able to provide a unique URL for each "likeable" item. This doesn't have to be accessible from your frontend but it does have to accessible by the Facebook **scraper** .

What I have done in past projects is create a unique URL for any Facebook related **scraping** (for example `share_content.php`) and this page would be in charge of displaying the correct `og` tags as requested.

For example:

```
 http://my-cool-site.com/share_content.php?item_id=5
```

The `share_content` code will extract the `item_id` and populate the HTML with the `og` tags containing values of item 5.

---

As you probably don't want normal users to be able to access those pages that are generated specifically for Facebook, you could try to recognize and identify Facebook's **scraper** and only show the content to it - if a normal user accesses those pages, you could perform a redirect to the actual resource.

There are couple of ways to detect Facebook's **scrapers** :

- [By IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859013/whats-the-ip-address-range-of-facebooks-open-graph-crawler)
- [By user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881609/how-to-identify-a-facebook-bot) (not recommended)

Comment: @TwiStar - woah...well.. yea... It sounds like it does exactly what you need. The question is are you willing to maintain another "server" for this?

Comment: Well, since the only server i have is a REST Api written with Yii framework with zero server-side rendering, i guess setting up another server might be way less painful than writing like 20 views for facebook like-and-share plugin.

Comment: @TwiStar - My intention was to only write one view that would receive parameters - but if you have no server side code to handle this I suppose using this other solution would work too.