# CIDR notation on Cloudflare for facebook crawler

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, cloudflare, cidr

I'm using [cloudflare](http://www.cloudflare.com) as CDN provider, unfortunately I'm having issue with the facebook crawler when supposedly someone want to share article from the website and the open graphs don't get loaded properly with message:

> Attention Required | cloudflare If you are on personal connection,
>   like at home, you can run an anti-virus on your device to make sure it
>   is not infected with malware.

I'm pretty sure this is because I use cloudflare challenge passage to user before accessing the website.

I've read some of the IPs suggestions like on this thread ([What's the IP address range of Facebook's Open Graph crawler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859013/whats-the-ip-address-range-of-facebooks-open-graph-crawler)), but the problem with cloudflare is that the CIDR notation for acceptable IP Range are **only /16 and /24**. But the IP list on this thread suggests like:

```
31.13.24.0/21
31.13.64.0/18
66.220.144.0/20
69.63.176.0/20
69.171.224.0/19
74.119.76.0/22
103.4.96.0/22
173.252.64.0/18
204.15.20.0/22
```

What I've done so far is to add this list of IPs with notation /24 at the end, but still not working.

Anyone having similar experience like this and know the work around?

Comment: Did you re-scrape your URLs after making those changes in your cloudfare configuration?

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean by re-scraping. Please explain more Cbroe. Thanks.

Comment: Facebook caches the data it has read from your URLs – so when you changed your configuration, you need to make the FB scraper request your pages again, if you want to see any effect. The easiest way to do this is using the debug tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ Try that first with one of your URLs, to see if your changes fixed anything.

Comment: yes, I did. and the result stil the same. and sorry for the late reply. i was away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally able to solve this by adding /16 CIDR notion for each IP range instead. Example: 31.13.24.0/21 => 31.13.0.0/16. Hope it helps others who need it.