# What's the IP address range of Facebook's Open Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I did found a duplicated question about this topic right here [What's the IP address range of Facebook's Open Graph crawler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859013/whats-the-ip-address-range-of-facebooks-open-graph-crawler)

But just to verify the IP address range that the question's answer provided is accurate as of April 2012. Is that range of IP address still accurate for now as 2018?

The IP address range shown in the question is

```
31.13.24.0/21
31.13.64.0/18
66.220.144.0/20
69.63.176.0/20
69.171.224.0/19
74.119.76.0/22
103.4.96.0/22
173.252.64.0/18
204.15.20.0/22
```

In order for our "intranet" system which not allow any internet access has the facebook SSO feature, we need to configure on the firewall to allow the system access to the Facebook Graph API.

Comment: Use the `whois` command shown there and find out …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook has 1 AS Number: AS32934

For your ease, I have created a git repo with all the ipv4 and ipv6 ip addresses of Facebook, LinkedIn and Twitter. Please find them from the links below:

[Facebook IP Addresses](https://github.com/aarvee11/FacebookIPLists)

[LinkedIn IP Addresses](https://github.com/aarvee11/LinkedInIPLists)

[Twitter IP Addresses](https://github.com/aarvee11/TwitterIPLists)

Do post your queries on the respective Github Repo's itself and I can help you in case of any !