# How can I stop facebook crawler causing high CPU usage

Tags: wordpress, facebook, web-crawler, cpu-usage

Hi I've recently been getting super high spikes in Apache CPU usage, Apache memory usage and MySQL memory usage. It turns out that crawlers were accessing my site at a very aggressive rate, specifically Facebook. I attempted to add a crawl delay for the facebook crawler to the robot.txt file, as seen below:

```
User-agent: Facebot
Disallow:
Crawl-delay: 5
```

but I'm still seeing high usage spikes. Is this due to incorrect code or is there a better way entirely to go about stopping crawlers using so much of my server's resources?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It seems this is still a current issue and FB crawler does not always play nicely

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521798/excessive-traffic-from-facebookexternalhit-bot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the path to

```
 Disallow: /
```

see [Robots FAQ](http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/prevent.html)